# Ajax frameworks small application

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, frameworks, echo2

I'm wondering if any of you have some ideas of a small application i can work on , just to get familiar with any of the Ajax Frameworks specially if it's  related to Java like JMaki or ECHO 2

thanks .

Comment: why do you want to "just get familiar" with any of the Ajax Frameworks? Answer that, and you might find you project... or just save yourself the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the dojo toolkit would be a good choice for you (www.dojotoolkit.org/). You'll find a good article/tutorial on "Dojo concepts for Java developers" at IBM (www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-dojo/). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

A small and simple application for which ajax is eminently suitable is a random quote generator or a Stock ticker simulation. Have an ajax type call update a field or label within an HTML page without refreshing the page. Make the ajax calls via a timed event schedule. Extend this simple example to interactive use of combo box selections to pull back specific quotations. Further extend it's capabilities by using AJAX calls to submit new quotations to the quotation store.

It's a simple scenario but it covers most of the basic interactions that can once learned be applied to more substantial tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting your feet wet with Ajax then you can use something like jQuery or DWR framework. That will get you the basic idea of how ajax works without getting into the intricate details of XmlHttpRequest object.

DWR website is pretty useful. You can look at their tutorials [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/examples/index.html). The Dynamic Text example tutorial is as simple as it gets.